# Tkinter name "X" is not defined error.

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to take a more object oriented approach by using classes, but I seem to be getting the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./Main.py", line 17, in
>   
>       Main = Menu(root)   File "./Main.py", line 11, in **init**
>       self.F1.pack(fill=X) NameError: global name 'X' is not defined

Here is the code I am trying to compile, I have broken it down to a simple snippet to show the error I am getting:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter as tk # Python 2 import

class Menu:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root = parent
        self.root.geometry("800x400")
        self.root.title("Image Compression")
        self.F1 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="black")
        self.F1.pack(fill=X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()  
    Main = Menu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For that style import, use `tk.X`, or `"X"`.

Comment: @Novel - I think you mean "x" instead of "X".  Most constant strings are lowercase...

Comment: you can use text `"x"` instead variable `X` or `tk.X` - `fill="x"` because variable `tk.X` has value string `"x"`

Comment: @Gary02127 The strings themselves are probably lowercase but the variables are uppercase.

Comment: @Coal_ - That is correct, Sir!  Tkinter.X is actually 'x', Tkinter.END is 'end', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
self.F1.pack(fill=X)
```

should be

```
self.F1.pack(fill=tk.X)
```

and you should also add `expand=True` to make the fill actually work.
Tkinter.X and Tkinter.Y and Tkinter.BOTH are constants (strings) that are defined in the Tkinter module. Without the `Tkinter.`, you are trying to access *X* as a variable.
Your line should read

```
self.F1.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)
```

to do what you want it to do.

Oh, one more afterthought... You may be thinking, "Hey! I've seen .pack(fill=X) working before!" This is true when there is a

```
from Tkinter import *
```

statement above the reference. Then, in that instance, **X** would be found as coming from Tkinter but without needing the leading `Tkinter.`. That's the topic of namespace, which is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Note you could also use: `self.F1.pack(fill='x')`.

Comment: @ChristianDean - That is very true, but I'm a firm believer in using constants instead of strings whenever possible, because I'd much rather discover a typo when I'm trying to run a script rather than trying to figure out later on why something's working, but not quite the way I expected it to... :)  I like constants for catching errors.

Comment: BTW: use `print(tk.X, type(tk.X))` and you will see this constants uses string `x <class 'str'>`

Comment: In a well-defined module like tkinter/Tkinter, using the constants is less important, because the module will probably identify the error. If I write .pack(fill='X'), Tkinter will complain about the 'X'. But in another scenario, in a less well-defined module, that mistake might go uncaught for a while. But if I used Tkinter.X, and I accidentally typed Tkinter.x, it would get flagged... I'm old school!  :)

Comment: I left out the expand just to demonstrate my error, thank you for your helpful answer. I am in fact using christian's method, seems to be much neater.